# Going offline with app and database syncing

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a NativeScript (Angular) app that makes API-calls to a server to get data. I want to implement a bi-directional synchronization once a device gets online but using current API, no BaaS.

I could do a sort of caching. Once in a while app invalidates info in database and fetches it again. I don't like this approach because there are big lists that may change. They are fetched in batches, i.e. by page. One of them is a list of files downloaded to and stored on a device. So I have to keep those that are still in the list, and delete those that are not. It sounds like a nightmare.

How would you solve such a problem?

Comment: You should probably use a background service / fetch, that runs every once in a while and sync data by hitting your apis.

Comment: The database can be large and I don't want to download it all without a need.

Answer (score 4):

I use nativescript-couchebase plugin to store the data. We have following services

1. Connectivity
2. Data
3. API Service

Based on connectivity is Online/Offline, we either fetch data from remote API or via couchebase db. Please note that API service always returns the data from Couchebase only.

So in online mode

API Call -> Write to DB -> Return latest data from Couchebase

Offline mode

Read DB -> Return latest data from Couchebase

Also along with this, we maintain all API calls in a queue. So whenever connectivity returns, API calls are processed in sequence. Another challenge that you may face while coming in online mode from offline mode is the token expiry. This problem can be solved by showing a small popup to user after you come online.

Comment: Thanks @Rajan Phatak, do you have an example or a tutorial how to implement it?

Comment: "API Call -> Write to DB -> Return latest data from Couchebase"
If I always return data from the Couchbase, how do I know when I should do an API call?

Comment: @jarod we will always know if we are connected or not via connectivity service. If offline, put API call in queue and return via db else update couchbase and then return. So best practice i feel is to return via local couchbase always

Comment: @RajanPhatak : Thats cool. But the hosting charges for couchbase is too much . We have a plan of creating an offline first accounting mobile app which needs online data sync only in fetching reports and login . Can you tell the cheapest hosting available ? I saw options like AWS,Google Cloud and Couchbase server.

Answer (score -1):

I do this by saving my data as a json string and saving it to the devices file system.

When the app loads/reloads I read it from the file.

ie.
   const fileSystemModule = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");

```
var siteid = appSettings.getNumber("siteid");
var fileName =  viewName + ".json";
const documents = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
const site_folder = documents.getFolder("site");
const siteid_folder = site_folder.getFolder(siteid.toString());

const directoryPath = fileSystemModule.path.join(siteid_folder.path, fileName);
const directoryFile = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(directoryPath);
directoryFile.writeText(json_string)
.then((result) => {
    directoryFile.readText().then((res) => {
        retFun(res);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```